# Error setting date of month to 31st

Tags: javascript, date

While setting the date to 31st we encountered this issue.

```js
function getTodayMidnight() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(1);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  return date;
}

function getDates() {
  var octStartDate = getTodayMidnight();
  octStartDate.setDate(1);
  octStartDate.setMonth(9);

  var octEndDate = getTodayMidnight();
  octEndDate.setDate(31);
  octEndDate.setMonth(9);
  console.log(octStartDate);
  console.log(octEndDate);
}

getDates();
```

I'm accounting for the date offset in my timezone `(+530, 330 mins)`. For start of the month case, the behaviour is expected. (We expect to go back to the previous month and display the date). But we are getting an erroneous output in the case of the last date of the month. Why are they pointing to the same date?

Comment: What output?...

Comment: `this issue` what issue? are timezones confusing you?

Comment: @JaromandaX why are both dates giving the result as `"2017-09-30T18:30:01.000Z"`?

Comment: ooh, sorry, didn't read the code right

Comment: The number of days in octEndDate depends on the current month. The rest is in the doucumentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

Comment: setmonth before setdate and it works OK -oops, answer explains it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you ran this program today (15th November), then `new Date()` returns a `Date` object with the month set to November.  So a call to `setDate(31)` will result in the [date overflowing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) to 1st December (because November only has 30 days).  You then call `setMonth(9)`, so the final result corresponds to 1st October.

Obviously, you can avoid this by switching the order of your method calls. 
 But to avoid this ordering problem entirely, I'd suggest using the `Date(year, month, date, ...)` constructor (this also avoids mutating a value type, which is generally considered to be a good thing).

Comment: That makes sense!